# Typography of nested quotations

Tags: typography, french, ifthenelse, quotation

In the case of nested quotations, we have the following rule in French typography: if two or more closing quotation marks follow one another, we will write only one closing quotation mark.

Thus:

> **«** Bla bla **«** bla bla bla **«** bla bla **»»»**

will become

> **«** Bla bla **«** bla bla bla **«** bla bla **»**

But

> **«** Bla bla **«** bla **«** bla bla **»** bla **»** bla **»**

stay

> **«** Bla bla **«** bla **«** bla bla **»** bla **»** bla **»**

How do you do that in LaTeX?

Here's where I'm stuck: I can't implement the "quotation marks must follow each other" condition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{nesting@depth}

\providecommand{\guillemets}[1]{%
    \addtocounter{nesting@depth}{1}%
    \og%
    #1%
    \ifthenelse%
        {\value{nesting@depth}>1}%
        {}%
        {\fg{}}%
    \addtocounter{nesting@depth}{-1}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\guillemets{Bla bla \guillemets{ bla bla bla \guillemets{bla bla}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a copy of Lexique des règles typographiques but I do not speak French. Can you please point to the section, page or paragraph where such rule is listed?

Comment: I didn't know, can you tell us where we can find this rule. «*Je l'ignorai, pouvez-vous indiquer où l'on peut trouver cette règle*»

Comment: @ivankokan Probably *Citations*, in particular *Citations de deuxième rang* (p 51) - 'If the two quotations [one enclosed within the other] finish together, only one closing *guillemet* will be typeset'.

Comment: Is the same rule applied when using quotes instead of guillemets?

Comment: @ivankokan Quotation marks (' ") aren't used, as far as I can tell. Only guillemets. And for quotations, guillemets are not used all the time even then: '...where there is no ambiguity, foreign language quotations are in italics without *guillemets*; otherwise, they are still in italics, but between *guillemets*.
Any translation is in roman between parentheses, outside the *guillemets* if the quotation has *guillemets*. The translation will be between *guillemets* if the quotation does not have any.' (p 52). PS: Use @ to ping me, otherwise I won't be notified.

Comment: @ivankokan Correction: Computer coding uses ' and " - says Wikipedia. Also, in Canadian French: « L’ouvreuse m’a dit : “Donnez-moi votre ticket.” Je le lui ai donné. » In France: « L’ouvreuse m’a dit : « Donnez-moi votre ticket. » Je le lui ai donné. » In Swiss typography: « L’ouvreuse m’a dit : ‹ Donnez-moi votre ticket. › Je le lui ai donné. »

Comment: @Cicada I suggest you review the existing four French configurations in `csquotes` package: https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/blob/d1b590ceffe4a56117357afe5b7211a720241760/csquotes.def#L95-L120, although I am pretty sure they are already aligned with the *Lexique*.

Comment: @ivankokan Thanks.

Comment: @ivankokan Yes, aligned. Unrelated - Very powerful and flexible package and coding!

Comment: Compliments to Mr. Joseph Wright!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `csquotes` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,maxlevel=3,french=guillemets]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\enquote{Bla bla \enquote{bla bla bla \enquote{bla bla}}}

\end{document}
```